# Vinculo de tabelas SQL por meio de string ao invés de id

Tags: mysql, join, chave-estrangeira

Dados das contas de usuários

```
id  nome    sobrenome   pais    estado  cidade  telefone    url_perfil
```

Dados de login dos usuários

```
id  email   senha   prioridade
```

As minhas dúvidas são:

- Como posso vincular elas com a `foreign key` usando `string` ?
- É mais recomendado fazer isso com a `ID` ? Por que? (Podem haver problemas na hora de um usuário cadastrar os dados dele em uma tabela, e a conta dele ter 2 `id`'s diferentes sendo uma por cada tabela, dificultando o uso da chave estrangeira ?)
- Para o uso da foreign key, é necessário que a `ENGINE` do banco seja `INNODB` ?
- Como seria o `Join` para essas tabelas ?

PS: Procurei pelo `stack` e outros lugares se havia uma "pergunta" que respondesse minhas dúvidas, ou pelo menos me desse uma luz, porém não encontrei, e devido a isso estou abrindo essa

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1545253/how-to-add-a-column-and-make-it-a-foreign-key-in-single-mysql-statement

Comment: tradução ? seria melhor :3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Para o uso da foreign key, é necessário que a ENGINE do banco seja INNODB ?

Ao utilizar esse engine o banco de dados garante de forma automática  a integridade referencial ela pode ser garantida via aplicação porém você programar as regras e tomar todos os devidos cuidados.

> Como posso vincular elas com a foreign key usando string ?

Sim pode. Funciona da mesma forma basta informar os nomes das colunas na chave estrangeira.

> Como seria o Join para essas tabelas?

É a mesma coisa.

> É mais recomendado fazer isso com a ID ? Por que? (Podem haver problemas na hora de um usuário cadastrar os dados dele em uma tabela, e a conta dele ter 2 id's diferentes sendo uma por cada tabela, dificultando o uso da chave estrangeira ?)

Em termos de performace comparações numericas são mais rápidas que comparações com strings (varchar). O tamanho do campo string influência no indice ou seja quanto maior pior a performace.

Ao se trabalhar com chaves não numerica o rigor de validação dos valores deve-se se maior por exemplo remover espaços, cuidar para não ter problemas com encodings.

Um exemplo de chave primária como string pode ser visto entre as tabelas cidade (FK) e estado (sigla + nome PK)

Comment: tentei usar o comando `alter table contas_dados add FOREIGN key(email_conta) references contas_login(email);`

Comment: Porém ocorreu o erro :  `#1005 - Não pode criar a tabela webtraining_contas.#sql-103c_27b (erro no. 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (Informações…)`

Comment: @MuriloGambôa sua PK na outra tabela é somente `email_conta` ou ela é composta?

Comment: PK ? eu coloquei o `email_conta` como `varchar(255) not null` apenas na hora de criar a tabela

Comment: @MuriloGambôa tem como colocar no pastbin ou na pergunta a criação das tabelas?

Comment: @MuriloGambôa fiz um teste aqui, primeiro tive que criar um indice para `email_conta` e depois dar um alter adicionando como chave estrangeira.